# Python GUI tkinter arduino serial data

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino, pyserial

Ok so im trying to separate my data from arduino into python GUI tkinter over serial port

Example: i have a Humidity and Temperature sensor also a light. I want Python GUI to read the serial communication and store the data in separate strings (temperature, humidity, light)

Python Code

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial #Serial imported for Serial communication
import time #Required to use delay functions
 
# Create the master object
root = tk.Tk()

ArduinoSerial = serial.Serial('com5',9600) #Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData
time.sleep(2)

humidity = tk.Label(root, text=ArduinoSerial.readline())
humidity.grid(row=0, column=0)

templabel = tk.Label(root, text="Temperature :" )
tempEntry = tk.Label(root, text=ArduinoSerial.readline() )

templabel.grid(row=1, column=0)
tempEntry.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Arduino Code

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>

int relayPin = 5; 
int relayPinW = 6;
int sOn = 3;
char serialData;

DHT my_sensor (3, DHT22);

float temperature, humidity;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  my_sensor.begin();
   pinMode (relayPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode (relayPinW, OUTPUT);
  
}

void loop() {
  
  //digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
  //Serial.print("Nano - Relay Open \n");
  //delay(8000);

  //if(sOn > 0){
  //digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
  //Serial.print("Nano - Relay CLOSED \n");
  //delay(8000);
  //}
  
  digitalWrite(relayPinW, HIGH);
  Serial.print("Nano - Water Pump is now active \n");
  delay(8000);
  
  digitalWrite(relayPinW, LOW);
  Serial.print("Nano - Water Pump OFF \n");
  delay(8000);
  
 if(humidity > 1)
  {
     digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
     Serial.print("Humidifer Is Now ** ON ** PIN5 \n");
  } else { 
    Serial.print("ERROR with Digital Write PIN");
  }
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
  serialData = Serial.read();
  Serial.print(serialData);
 
  humidity = my_sensor.readHumidity();
  temperature = my_sensor.readTemperature();

  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temperature);
  Serial.print("C / Humidity: ");
  Serial.print(humidity);
  Serial.println("%");
    
  
}
```

that works but i want the data to be separated into there own variables would i have to decode or encode? I'm very lost... THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to do the serial reading in a thread so that it won't block the main application.  Second both sides have to compromise the format of the data.

Below is an modified example based on your code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import serial #Serial imported for Serial communication
import threading

# Create the master object
root = tk.Tk()

ArduinoSerial = serial.Serial('com5', 9600) #Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData

def arduino_handler():
    while True:
        data = ArduinoSerial.readline().strip()
        if data.startswith("Temperature:"):
            temperature.set(data.split(":")[1])
        elif data.startswith("Humidity:"):
            humidity.set(data.split(":")[1])

tk.Label(root, text="Humidity:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
humidity = tk.StringVar()
tk.Label(root, textvariable=humidity).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w')

tk.Label(root, text="Temperature:" ).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
temperature = tk.StringVar()
tk.Label(root, textvariable=temperature).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')

threading.Thread(target=arduino_handler, daemon=True).start()
root.mainloop()
```

Then update Arduino program to output the required format:

```
void loop() {
    digitalWrite(relayPinW, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Nano - Water Pump is now active");
    delay(8000);

    digitalWrite(relayPinW, LOW);
    Serial.println("Nano - Water Pump OFF");
    delay(8000);

    if(humidity > 1)
    {
        digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
        Serial.println("Humidifer Is Now ** ON ** PIN5");
    } else {
        Serial.println("ERROR with Digital Write PIN");
    }
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        serialData = Serial.read();
        Serial.print(serialData);

        humidity = my_sensor.readHumidity();
        temperature = my_sensor.readTemperature();

        Serial.print("Temperature:");
        Serial.println(temperature);
        Serial.print("Humidity:");
        Serial.print(humidity);
        Serial.println("%");
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\ii\python\GUI\test2.py", line 13, in arduino_handler
    if data.startswith("Temperature:"):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str

Comment: It gives me this error.. not sure what threading would do to help this. from what im understanding theres to many things printed into the serial. which i agree. i was thinking i can simplify them down to there exact values

Comment: Example would be Tempature: 22.0 Humidity : 33.0 Water Pump 1/ON Light 1/ON and in the serial it would look like this 22.0 x 33.0 x 1 x 1

Comment: then i was thinking on spliting the "x" and storing them as floats... but im not sure on how to do that

Comment: For the exception, try changing the line `data = ArduinoSerial.readline().strip()` to `data = ArduinoSerial.readline().decode().strip()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hay, Hi 
you just need to format type 
means in your python code 
where it is \

```
humidity = tk.Label(root, text=ArduinoSerial.readline())
humidity.grid(row=0, column=0)

templabel = tk.Label(root, text="Temperature :" )
tempEntry = tk.Label(root, text=ArduinoSerial.readline() )
```

just you `unicode` function
means your code should look like:- \

```
humidity = tk.Label(root, text=unicode(ArduinoSerial.readline()))
humidity.grid(row=0, column=0)

templabel = tk.Label(root, text="Temperature :" )
tempEntry = tk.Label(root, text=unicode(ArduinoSerial.readline()) )
```

It will solve your issue.
But this has a drawback because you are printing too many things in serial
so,
you need to optimize your Arduino code

At last one small tip:-
you can use `println()` function instead fo `print("....\n")`